# Python Pandas - Removing Rows From A DataFrame Based on a Previously Obtained Subset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running `Python 2.7` with the `Pandas 0.11.0` library installed.

I've been looking around a haven't found an answer to this question, so I'm hoping somebody more experienced than I has a solution.

Lets say my data, in df1, looks like the following:

`df1=`

```
  zip  x  y  access
  123  1  1    4
  123  1  1    6
  133  1  2    3
  145  2  2    3
  167  3  1    1
  167  3  1    2
```

Using, for instance, `df2 = df1[df1['zip'] == 123]` and then `df2 = df2.join(df1[df1['zip'] == 133])` I get the following subset of data:

`df2=`

```
 zip  x  y  access
 123  1  1    4
 123  1  1    6
 133  1  2    3
```

What I want to do is either:

1) Remove the rows from `df1` as they are defined/joined with `df2`

OR

2) After `df2` has been created, remove the rows (difference?) from `df1` which `df2` is composed of

Hope all of that makes sense.  Please let me know if any more info is needed.

EDIT:

Ideally a third dataframe would be create that looks like this:

`df2=`

```
 zip  x  y  access
 145  2  2    3
 167  3  1    1
 167  3  1    2
```

That is, everything from `df1` not in `df2`.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what output you want.  Do you just want to break the dataframe into two new dataframes, one composed of rows where the `zip` column is 123 or 133 and one composed of the rest?

Comment: @DSM I edited the question- what I'm looking for is at the bottom.  Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Two options come to mind.  First, use `isin` and a mask:

```
>>> df
   zip  x  y  access
0  123  1  1       4
1  123  1  1       6
2  133  1  2       3
3  145  2  2       3
4  167  3  1       1
5  167  3  1       2
>>> keep = [123, 133]
>>> df_yes = df[df['zip'].isin(keep)]
>>> df_no = df[~df['zip'].isin(keep)]
>>> df_yes
   zip  x  y  access
0  123  1  1       4
1  123  1  1       6
2  133  1  2       3
>>> df_no
   zip  x  y  access
3  145  2  2       3
4  167  3  1       1
5  167  3  1       2
```

Second, use `groupby`:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby(df['zip'].isin(keep))
```

and then any of

```
>>> grouped.get_group(True)
   zip  x  y  access
0  123  1  1       4
1  123  1  1       6
2  133  1  2       3
>>> grouped.get_group(False)
   zip  x  y  access
3  145  2  2       3
4  167  3  1       1
5  167  3  1       2
>>> [g for k,g in list(grouped)]
[   zip  x  y  access
3  145  2  2       3
4  167  3  1       1
5  167  3  1       2,    zip  x  y  access
0  123  1  1       4
1  123  1  1       6
2  133  1  2       3]
>>> dict(list(grouped))
{False:    zip  x  y  access
3  145  2  2       3
4  167  3  1       1
5  167  3  1       2, True:    zip  x  y  access
0  123  1  1       4
1  123  1  1       6
2  133  1  2       3}
>>> dict(list(grouped)).values()
[   zip  x  y  access
3  145  2  2       3
4  167  3  1       1
5  167  3  1       2,    zip  x  y  access
0  123  1  1       4
1  123  1  1       6
2  133  1  2       3]
```

Which makes most sense depends upon the context, but I think you get the idea.