# Create a new dictionary comparing to a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary. I want to create a new dictionary comparing a list, (`my_list`) of values to my dictionary's values.

My dictionary, `code_dict` keys and values:

```
33003282 :['25000', '27800', 'None', '4779'], 
33003283: ['2564', '6264', '78784', '7841', '89564'], 
33003285: ['32723', '8954', '5259', '5225', '25000','04189', '8820', '2166']
```

I have `my_list` like this:

```
my_list = ['27800', '6264', '5225']
```

Now, I want to compare my list values to Dictionary values and create a new dictionary that has values like this,

```
33003282 :['25000', 'None', '4779'], 
33003283: ['2564','78784', '7841', '89564'], 
33003285: ['32723', '8954', '5259', '25000','04189', '8820', '2166']
```

I did the following in comprehension way hoping that I could do like how we do it in [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704782/python-pandas-removing-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-a-previously-obtained-su):

```
new_dict = {key: value for value in code_dict.items()}.isin([code for code in my_list])
```

using `isin` in dictionaries does not work, how can I create a new dictionary?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with the dict comprehension? Just print values? If so, don't use a comprehension for that, it's called a side effect, and is not recommended.

Comment: That seems like a more interesting problem to solve, you should edit your question accordingly with some input and expected output by means of a [mcve]. :-)

Comment: What about using it like that: {key: value for key,value in code_dict.items()} ?

Comment: If you just want the values, use `list(code_dict.values())` to get a list of only them. BTW, there is no dictionary `isin` method.

Comment: So, you want to retain only those list items that _are_ in mylist? Or _are not_? (expected output would've been helpful).

Comment: There's no such thing as `isin`.

Comment: Actually, `code_dict.items()` returns a tuple of items. And `keys` seems to have been predefined by you (as one of the keys), otherwise you'd get a `NameError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
d = {33003282 :['25000', '27800', 'None', '4779'], 33003283: ['2564', '6264', '78784', '7841', '89564'],33003285: ['32723', '8954', '5259', '5225', '25000','04189', '8820', '2166']}
my_list = ['27800', '6264', '5225']
final_d = {a:[i for i in b if i not in my_list] for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{33003282: ['25000', 'None', '4779'], 33003283: ['2564', '78784', '7841', '89564'], 33003285: ['32723', '8954', '5259', '25000', '04189', '8820', '2166']}
```

The output is a dictionary where the values are filtered so that none of its elements exist in `my_list`

Comment: this is Neat! My purpose was different, but seems like the way to go! I'll accept this as answer!

Comment: @i.n.n.m glad to help!